# EMR Cluster logs to cloudwatch

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-emr

Our  Apache-Flink Job runs on EMR cluster, we have the logs produced to EMR as logs are available for limited amount of time: how to produce them to Cloudwatch?

Comment: That would probably involve locating logs that you are interested in, installing the CloudWatch agent to the EC2 Instances and configuring it to collect the logs. Please see pages [Collecting Apache Flink metrics in the Amazon CloudWatch agent](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/collecting-apache-flink-metrics-amazon-cloudwatch-agent/) and [Manually create or edit the CloudWatch agent configuration file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html#CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Logssection).

Comment: Also, please note that CloudWatch is not the only way to persistently store the logs: you can provide LogUri when you create an EMR cluster which will enable archiving of logs to S3. I don't know how well Apache Flink's logs are supported though. Please see page [Configure cluster logging and debugging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-debugging.html).